# Footnotemarks for same reference inside an overlay

Tags: beamer, footnotes, overlays

I'm sorry in advance that I can't post a minimum workable example, but I haven't access to the PC that actually have the TEX file until next Monday.

I'm working on a presentation with `beamer`, and all the images have a footnote with the reference. I've done that with the `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` workaround (cause the image are in a column environment).

There is two or three slide when I show the same image with modification that I uncover step-by-step (multiple image with added lines and polygons in photoshop that are inserted in `beamer` with `\includegraphics` with the overlay options.
So I have many `\includegraphics<1-3,9>` with different overlays for example.
The image in particular is a skull, and step by step I add lines and boxes that show some acronyms and some particular position. So I'd like to have a column with the text, and with the prosecute of the pdf the same image but with added particular on top of that.

The basic image obviously is the same, only with some polygons addes, and have the same origin, so need the same footnote that specify the book reference.

When I use the `footnotemark`, with or without `[]` a number specification on every line of the image environment, I get a PDF with the correct image, of course, but with many numerical mark that float in the white space, like the `footnotemark` add multiple times the same number or an increase number.

For example, I have one image, with three polygons on it. This image is showed in the first three overlay and in the last, when I recap the entire slide.
Then I have below this image a 14 14 14 14 14 etc, all the mark for the footnote (if I have specified for all the `footnotemark` a `[14]`).
If I use only a mark on the last image, I have no number for the previous image and a correct mark only in the last one.

There is a way to mark this multiple image with a single and stable mark through the slide? So the image in the PDF change with the added lines and polygons without mess with the reference for the footnote?

I've tried two things:
First: put this images one by one in different frame. So no overlay, but one frame with exact same text but different image. It's ok but all the footnote need to be numbered manually.
Second: list all the `includegraphics` with the different images, and only after that use a `footnotemark`. This work, but than I have all the presentation with a small mark-number in the bottom-right corner of the figures, and this two or three frame (and for frame I mean beamer-frame, so three different things) that have a small number about one line and a half below the image.

Sorry for the very verbose post and maybe for the bad english, but this is not my native language and maybe I overdo a little with unneeded description of the problem, my fault.
If the problem is not solvable without a MWE than I will edit this post the next Monday. I would have liked to have some advice before Monday in order to resolve this first thing that day.

Thanks in advance,

A.E.

EDIT: I've attached a very simple file that I've make now on-the-go.
The idea is the same, a list on a column, and an image on the left. Same images but not identical, with different layer that I've make with paint.
The source of the basic image the skull, is a book that I need to cite.
Don't pay attention to the overlay of the text, in the original file the first four and last four are grouped because the image is from a different views (same page of the same book though.
Don't pay attention to the `addtocounter`, is a thing that make things work with the numeration cause many mark in the previous slide are done manually.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
    %\author{}
    %\title{}
    %\subtitle{}
    %\logo{}
    %\institute{}
    %\date{}
    %\subject{}
    %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
    %\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \frame[plain]{\maketitle}

    \begin{frame}\frametitle{What we measure?} \framesubtitle{Body measurements:}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.40\textwidth}
                Head-portion measurements:
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item<1-4,9> HL
                    \item<2-4,9> HW
                    \item<3-4,9> IO
                    \item<4,9> IN 
                    \item<5-8,9> NE
                    \item<6-8,9> HH
                    \item<7-8,9> ED
                    \item<8,9> ML
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.60\textwidth}
                \centering {
                    \includegraphics<1>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull1} \par \only<1>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
                    \includegraphics<2>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull2} \par \only<2>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
                    \includegraphics<3>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull3} \par \only<3>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
                    \includegraphics<4>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull4} \par \only<4>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
                    \includegraphics<5>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull5} \par \only<5>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
                    \includegraphics<6>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull6} \par \only<6>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
                    \includegraphics<7>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull7} \par \only<7>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
                    \includegraphics<8>[width=1\columnwidth]{skull8} \par \only<8>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
                    \includegraphics<9>[width=0.70\columnwidth]{skull9} \par \only<9>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme} }
                }\footnotemark
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
        \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
        \footnotetext{Edited version \\ \hspace{1em} Original from \cite{randomcitation}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you just make a small sketch which numbers/notes/images should be on which slides? I guess you want to surround some commands with `\only` or use something like `\footnotetext<1>{text}`.

Comment: I've edited my original post.
That example is with the footnotemark at the end of the image environment, and not inside (a footnotemark per each image).

With many mark I obtain a list of number in every slide, and not one mark only. I need a single footnote number (14) in the bottom-right corner of the image. A single small 14 that refer all this images to a single source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, quite "banal".
For those who will may find this useful:

Every single image need an addictional personal footnotemark inside an `\only<>`.

So I have a `<>` option number for the `\includegraphics`, an `\only<>` for a `\footnotemark[]` with the number option specified, and finally a `\only<>` for the caption of the images.
Every number inside <> is the same.

My first mistake was to believe that a `\footnotemark` directly attached to an image with an overlay specified applied automatically the same overlay of the image to the mark.

Example:

```
\includegraphics<1>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestasuperiore0}\only<1>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<1>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }   
\includegraphics<2>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestasuperiore1}\only<2>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<2>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
\includegraphics<3>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestasuperiore2}\only<3>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<3>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
\includegraphics<4>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestasuperiore3}\only<4>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<4>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
\includegraphics<5>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestasuperiore4}\only<5>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<5>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - top view} }
\includegraphics<6>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestalaterale0}\only<6>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<6>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
\includegraphics<7>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestalaterale1}\only<7>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<7>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
\includegraphics<8>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestalaterale2}\only<8>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<8>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
\includegraphics<9>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestalaterale3}\only<9>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<9>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
\includegraphics<10>[width=1\columnwidth]{anatomiatestalaterale4}\only<10>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<10>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme - lateral view} }
\includegraphics<11>[width=0.60\columnwidth]{anatomiatesta}\only<11>{\footnotemark[15]} \par \only<11>{\footnotesize{\textit{Podarcis} spp. head scheme} }
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\addtocounter{footnote}{2}
\footnotetext{Edited version \\ \hspace{1em} Original from \cite{citazione2016random}}
```